# Ubuntu Server 14.04 eth0 loads not load after 1st updates

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, dhcp

I have a fresh install of Server 14.04 running on an old Dell OptiPlex 755 MT. It automatically connects to my network and I can reach it through SSH without an issue. I also made sure to edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` to add the `auto eth0` and `iface eth0 inet dhcp`, which I will set a static IP once I'm ready to place the server.

I run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and install the 100+ updates available and reboot. When it comes back up, `eth0` is no longer connected and I have to run

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

and dhclient to bring it back up each time. The `/etc/network/interfaces` file still shows my `eth0` information, but the OS doesn't seem to read it.

Is there a certain update from the initial set that is causing this? If so, which one is it so I can remove it? Apologies ahead of time, I'm fairly new to Linux and haven't been able to track down a solution.

Comment: Your system may be using Consistent Network Device Naming, which names network interfaces determined by how they're attached to your motherboard. Were there any other interfaces listed in `/etc/network/interfaces` (other that `lo` and `virbr0`)?

Comment: May we see: `ifconfig` and also: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: All I have in ifconfig is the lo after applying updates. In /etc/network/interfaces I have 'auto lo' 'iface lo inet loopback' followed by 'auto eth0' 'iface eth0 inet dhcp'. I did a fresh install on another machine without doing the apt-get update/upgrade and it connects with no issue. It's only after I apply the initial updates I lose connectivity and have to manually start the interface and run dhclient.

Comment: UPDATE: I added a wireless card to test a fresh install. It appeared in the /etc/network/interfaces and I applied a static address to it and it connected fine. I downloaded and applied the first round of patches and the same thing happened. Both eth0 and wlan0 do not load and have to be manually started after every reboot after the patches are applied.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Fresh install on a HP microserver gen8. Works like a charm, network was called **em1**. In the log it showed that udev had renamed **eth0** to **em1**.

Afther update with aptitude, the rename was gone from the log files, and I had an **eth0** interface.

Sollution **one**:
 sudo vim /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

change the line:
**SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add",  ...... KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"**

into
**SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add",  ...... KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="em1"**

Sollution **two**
You can also change /etc/network/interfaces.

Modify the two lines that read **em1** into **eth0**.

Don't know what is best. I was used to **eth0** from my previus Slackware server so I sticked to **eth0**.

Do think it is bad that a LTS build changes network names on a update!! Using the ILO evaluation license I can now access the console, but otherwise I would have had to attach a keyboard an screen to fix this.